# How to check the number of threads used on a program

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using Ubuntu18.04 and the program I am running is MyCC downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sb2nhri/files/MyCC/.

MyCC.py has some options such as :

```
-a A file having coverage information. 
    -t Minimum contig length. [defaults: 1000 bp]
    -lt A fraction of contigs for the first-stage clustering. [default: 0.7]
    -ct Minimum contig lengh for first stage clustering. [bp]
    -meta Change to meta mode of Prodigal. [default: single]
    -p Perplexity for BH-SNE. [default: 20, range between 5 and 50]
    -pm To set preferences all equal to the median of the other similarities for affinity propagation.
    -st Maximum distance for sparse format of affinity propagation. [default: 500]
    -mask To mask repetitive sequences.
    -keep To keep temporary files.
```

But does not have any option to control the number of threads. How can I verify the number of threads used? Thank you.

Comment: Check here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/88972/how-to-get-from-terminal-total-number-of-threads-per-process-and-total-for-al

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found out the number of threads used thanks to you @MeteHanKahraman